# Flash cc as3 how to make a child object be effected the same way as the parent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, physics, gravity, flash-cc

I have generated a piece of code, with help of this message board, but it is one problem after another. This time I have it so when you click on an object a new object spawns, but I need it so the child (the one that has been spawned) is effected by the gravity physics in place.

Here is my code:

```
var drag:Number = 1;
var BlockAppear = new MovieClip;

gotoAndStop(1, "Minigame-Block");

HeartBear.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_4);

import flash.events.MouseEvent;

HBS.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addHeart);

function addHeart(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var H=new HB;
    H.y = 523;
    H.x = 721;
    addChild(H);  //need the child to be effected by the gravity physics.
}

Block.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey_3);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed_3);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed_3);

function fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey_3(event:Event)
{
    if (leftPressed)
    {
        Blockr.x -= 5;
    }
    if (rightPressed)
    {
        Block.x += 5;
    }
}

function fl_SetKeyPressed_3(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function fl_UnsetKeyPressed_3(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function fl_ClickToDrag_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    HeartBear.startDrag()
    gravity = 0
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_4);

function fl_ReleaseToDrop_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    HeartBear.stopDrag();
    gravity = 0.9
}

var gravity = 0.8;
var floor = 523.3;
var onFloor:Boolean = false;

HeartBear.y = floor;
HeartBear.speedY = 0;
HeartBear.jump = 15;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterframe);
function enterframe(e:Event) {
    HeartBear.speedY += gravity;
    HeartBear.y += HeartBear.speedY;
    if(HeartBear.y > floor) {
        HeartBear.speedY = 0;
        HeartBear.y = floor;
        onFloor = true;           //gravity physics
    }

}
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, space);
function space(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP && onFloor) {
        HeartBear.speedY = -HeartBear.jump;
        onFloor = false;
    }
}

Shopclicker.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_3);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndStop(1, "Shop");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
function enterframe(e:Event) {
    HeartBear.speedY += gravity;
    HeartBear.y += HeartBear.speedY;
    if(HeartBear.y > floor) {
        HeartBear.speedY = 0;
        HeartBear.y = floor;
        onFloor = true;           //gravity physics
    }

}
```

to

```
function enterframe(e:Event) {
    e.currentTarget.speedY += gravity;
    e.currentTarget.y += e.currentTarget.speedY;
    if(e.currentTarget.y > floor) {
        e.currentTarget.speedY = 0;
        e.currentTarget.y = floor;
        onFloor = true;           //gravity physics
    }

}
```

and change

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enter frame);
```

to

```
HeartBear.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterframe);
```

and change

```
function addHeart(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var H=new HB;
    H.y = 523;
    H.x = 721;
    addChild(H);  //need the child to be effected by the gravity physics.
}
```

to

```
function addHeart(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var H=new HB;
    H.y = 523;
    H.x = 721;
    addChild(H);  //need the child to be effected by the gravity physics.
    H.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterframe);
}
```

And try to camel-case your variable and function names as well as class names.

Comment: How can I also make it so they are effected by drag and drop physics??? I already have this code but it only effects the parent. To make it so it effect the child as welll shall I change HeartBear to e.currentTarget???

Comment: @user3406023 First, did you make the changes said in my answer? It's adding the enter frame event that applies gravity to every newly created HB class and `event.currentTarget` applies to what movie clip the event is modifying.

Comment: Also gravity does not effect the object until the other object the parent is dropped, so it will sustain in mid air.

Comment: @user3406023 Change `function fl_ClickToDrag_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    HeartBear.startDrag()
    gravity = 0
}`

to

`function fl_ClickToDrag_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.currentTarget.startDrag()
    gravity = 0
}` and add `H.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_4);` to the `addHeart` function.

Comment: I can drag the child now ;) but gravity is not effecting it still, well not until the parent is dropped so it still stays stationary.